# multiple image upload using proffer in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, image-uploading

I am using CakePHP 3.2 and proffer plugin to upload images.

I have `products` and `product_images` table and using single form to upload data to two tables.

This is how my form is

```
<?= $this->Form->create($product, ['type' => 'file') ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('title', ['required' => true]) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('description', ['required' => true]) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('product_images.0.image', ['required' => true, 'type' => 'file']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('product_images.1.image', ['type' => 'file']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('submit', ['type' => 'submit']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

and controller is like

```
public function add()
{
   $product = $this->Products->newEntity();
   if ($this->request->is('post')) {
     $product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->data, [
        'associated' => ['ProductImages']
     ]);

     if ($this->Products->save($product)) {
        $this->Flash->success('Product saved');
     }
   }
}
```

But this is saving data to products table only and not to product images.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your models are correctly associated

```
<?= $this->Form->create($product, ['type' => 'file']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('title', ['required' => true]) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('description', ['required' => true]) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('product_images.0', ['required' => true, 'type' => 'file']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('product_images.1', ['type' => 'file']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('submit', ['type' => 'submit']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Add name images to save in database

```
public function add()
    {
       $product = $this->Products->newEntity();
       if ($this->request->is('post')) {
           $product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->data);

         foreach($product['product_images'] as $image) {
             //Add image name who you want to save in database
             $product['product_images'][]['image'] = $image['name'];    
         }

         if ($this->Products->save($product)) {
            $this->Flash->success('Product saved');
         }
       }
    }
```